# found ' Failed: Implicit Wait timed out after 30000ms' this error after play the testcase

Tags: timeout, selenium-ide

My problem is that my code found a timed out error. This is my code:

```
{
  "id": "7cff5f0f-49a0-4099-a4b4-6e50d5f38a1c",
  "comment": "",
  "command": "click",
  "target": "name=OrderSearch[order_id]",
  "targets": [
    ["name=OrderSearch[order_id]", "name"],
    ["css=input[name=\"OrderSearch[order_id]\"]", "css"],
    ["css=td:nth-child(1) > .form-control", "css:finder"],
    ["xpath=//input[@name='OrderSearch[order_id]']", "xpath:attributes"],
    ["xpath=//tr[@id='w0-filters']/td/input", "xpath:idRelative"],
    ["xpath=//input", "xpath:position"]
  ],
  "value": ""
}
```